# Minimum voltage for DC amplifier

Tags: dc-amplifier

Based on [Detecting a low pulse from an electromagnet induction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96058/detecting-a-low-pulse-from-an-electromagnet-induction),
I was planning to amplify a DC sine/sqaure wave, however the peak is less than 50mV.
What is the smallest voltage peak that can be amplified using a DC amplifier?

Comment: How do you define a DC wave?  Do you mean it is a varying signal that never goes negative ( or the other polarity? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real limit to amplifying even a sub pico-volt signal. Whether you can extract that signal from noise is a different matter entirely. The noise can be already present on your signal or, it can be added by the amplifier. For op-amps there are a couple of numbers in the data sheet that describes how much the amplifier adds noise.

Voltage noise density describes the effective power per hertz of bandwidth. A reasonable op-amp will have a figure like 10 nV per \$\sqrt{Hz}\$. This may seem confusing but if you square the voltage noise density and reference it to 1 ohm it becomes power per hertz. If you have a signal that can occupy a bandwidth of 20 kHz (i.e. audio) you take the square root of 20,000 (equals 141) and multiply that by the 10nV (=1.41\$\mu\$ volts). This is the equivalent RMS voltage at the input to your amplifier. If the amp has a gain of 1000, then the output noise is 1.41 milli volts RMS. To get a reasonable feel for this as a peak-to-peak signal, multiply it by 6.6. Why 6.6? It's all about the density of noise being gaussian in nature and multiplying by 6.6 means you have applied 6.6 standard deviations to a random signal in order to predict what the extremes are (within a confidence level of 99.9%): -

[image]

Another pointer to noise in the op-amp is low frequency peak-to-peak noise. It is specified differently to voltage noise density (above) because it is a different noise source. Normally this covers the frequency range 0.1Hz to 10Hz and is specified in \$\mu\$ volts p-p. If your frequency band of interest covers this area it has to be taken into account.

Current noise density is like voltage noise density except it defines what the bias current noises are from the input transistors. To convert to an equivalent voltage it is multiplied by the (external) source resistances in and around your input circuits.

And finally (probably), there is the noise of the resistors themselves. This is nothing to do with your amplifier. The voltage noise of a resistor is: -

\$\sqrt{4\cdot k_B\cdot T\cdot R\cdot \Delta F}\$

Where

- \$k_B\$ is Boltzmanns's constant
- T is absolute temperature in kelvins
- R is resistance in ohms
- \$\Delta F\$ is the frequency range you are interested in.

For a 1k ohm resistor at normal ambient temperature (300K) it will produce a voltage noise density of about 4nV per \$\sqrt{Hz}\$.

And after you've calculated the three noise densities (voltage noise, current noise and resistor noise) you can add them all together by using \$\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}\$ to get an equivalent input noise. I always treat the 0.1Hz to 10Hz noise as a separate entity and don't mix it in with the three noise densities just mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I havent had much experience with transistor amplifier circuits. I did try to look for some online. I was making an amplifier for a 60mv pulse. Do you have some suggestions on what I should be looking for?

Comment: I'd use an opamp as my first consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Analog signals are continuous.  A good amplifier will multiply whatever comes in by the gain factor.  It doesn't matter whether that is 1 V or 10 µV.  If the amplifier has a voltage gain of 10, for example, then the 1 V input will cause a 10 V output, and the 10 µV input will cause a 100 µV output.

However, the real issue is not about how small a signal a amplifier can amplify, but how small a signal can be in your system before it gets buried in the noise.  This metric depends on two things, how large the noise is in your system, and how much stronger the signal needs to be than the noise to serve its purpose.  The latter is called the *signal to noise ratio*, and is usually expressed in dB.

Let's say for example that all sources of noise on the output signal of your amplifier amount to 100 µV when referenced back to the input.  If you put in a signal from a microphone that produces 1 mV, then you have a 10:1 signal to noise ratio, which is better expressed as 20 dB.  You could certainly understand someone talking with 20 dB signal to noise ratio, but you'd also definitely hear the noise.

That might be like someone talking next to a sink with the water running.  It would be usable but would be considered pretty crappy for voice communication.  You'd complain to the phone company if your calls sounded like that, and it would be totally unacceptable for music.  For "Hi-Fi" audio you usually *start* at 90 dB or so and try to go up from there.  On the other hand, if you are sending a digital stream of fixed known high and low levels, 20 dB signal to noise ratio is plenty to reliably detect the digital signal at the other end.

Note that the gain of the amplifier has nothing to do with this, which is one reason it is convenient to project all noise back to the input.  In other words, you model the amp as being perfect with a certain amount of noise added to its input signal.  Cranking up the gain increases the noise along with the desired signal, so the signal to noise ratio stays the same.

For a DC amp, you have the additional considerations of *offset voltage* and *drift*.  One way of thinking about the offset voltage is that it's DC noise.  It is a constant error added to the input signal.  Drift is how much this constant varies over time.  The reason these can be ignored for AC amps is that AC by definition means frequencies above 0, and DC is exactly 0.  AC amps block from DC (0 Hz) up to some minimum frequency where they start amplifying at.  For Hi-Fi audio for example, it is acceptable to block frequencies below 20 Hz since we can't hear them.  The DC offset (0 Hz) and the drift (very close to 0 Hz) are ignored by AC amps so don't matter.